# SSH from windows Jenkins slave to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins

I have a windows jenkins slave.From this slave i want to SSH in linux.

Below i have given in Jenkinsfile

```
  bat 'ssh -p 22 -pw Qwerty@118 pxx1g9x@1x.1xx.13x.3x'
```

Here,pxx1g9x is the user and Qwerty@118 is the password for this user.1x.1xx.13x.3x is Ip of linux machine.

But this is giveing me below error

```
   ssh: Could not resolve hostname 118: No such host is known.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can directly pass the password as an argument in ssh, However, you might want to try adding the public key of the slave to the authorized hosts on the linux system.

You can see how it is done here.
https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

Comment: Unfortunately no public keys are created.So i have to use password only